# Accessing JavaScript object from separate window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using [fullCalendar.js](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/) as part of my web application.

When a calendar date is clicked, a window pops up, allowing the user to enter details about calendar events, and to save them.

I want to be able to trigger a function in the calendar object from the opened window.

Does Javascript have the facility to address objects from separate windows?

I have tried many ways of accessing the fullCalendar() object from a different window, but none has worked.

stuff like
 `$(window.opener.document.body).find('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`

Specifically I'm targeting the [`refetchEvents`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) hook.

Nothing like this, or any variant on it has worked so far.... there are many ways of addressing the object, but none that can reference an 'instance' within a separate document.

What's going on here?

Is it impossible to reference my calendar object from a separate window?

Really appreciate the pointers.

Edit ------------------

I've just tried:

`console.log(window.opener.calendar.fullCalendar())`

this produces a promising result, it's found the function, unfortunately now all of its internal references are messed up.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventSources' of undefined
m.fn.fullCalendar:8888/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js:110
$.ajax.successhlc.js:892
f.Callbacks.ojquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWithjquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
wjquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

Apart from that, no change so far. Implementing a new function now.

Still dealing with global `var calendar`

Comment: Is it a window or a div that pops?

Comment: It's a window... a div would have no trouble as it's the same doc. I want to keep the window pop-up, as for this app it works well.

Comment: binding issue? `console.log(window.opener.calendar.fullCalendar.bind(window.opener.calendar)())`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had just short glance at the fullCalendar code... but generally speaking how about trying:

defining in the opening window (`window.opener`) a function

```
function doRefetchEvents() {
  alert("ok");
  $("#calendar").fullCalender("refetchEvents");
}
```

and then from the opened window:

```
window.opener.doRefetchEvents();
```

see also [window.opener on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener)

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it came back as undefined, or as null object reference. Good idea though.

Comment: Did you try it out, loading both windows using the same script?

Comment: that should not make any difference I think... if you are accessing via window.opener you really refer to the opening window leaving the actual window alone... what does window.opener show in the console?

Comment: in the end I created a `loadCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth)` function to re-trigger the calendar, and used a fullcalendar.js hook to go to the specified date after it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the calendar object in the localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) by stringifying it (http://www.json.org/js.html -> JSON.stringify) and then, in the other window to access the object by parsing it with JSON.parse.

Comment: just to mention (as I looked through some questions): this won't work as JSON.stringify does actually nothing with functions but removing... I think this is even mentioned in the spec. see also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) section "Description" - If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted or censored to null